# Проблема с отображение вложенных элементов списка

Tags: html

Проблема заключается в том, что не хотят отображаться вложенные элементы списка. Вот мой код, вроде бы всё правильно:

```
<div id="block-category">

<p class="header-title" >Категории товаров</p>

<ul>

<li><a><img src="/images/syvenir-icon.gif" id="syvenir-images"/>Статуэтки</a>

<ul class="category-section">
<li><a href=""><strong>Все статуэтки</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="">Подраздел 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Подраздел 2</a></li>
</ul>

</li>

<li><a><img src="/images/svetilnik-icon.gif" id="svetilnik-images"/>3D 
Светильники</a>

<ul class="category-section">
<li><a href=""><strong>Все светильники</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="">Подраздел 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Подраздел 2</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><a><img src="/images/year-icon.gif" id="year-images"/>Новый год</a>

<ul class="category-section">
<li><a href=""><strong>Все сувениры</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="">Подраздел 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Подраздел 2</a></li>
</ul>

</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Вот так должно быть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня выходит так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код CSS:

```
/** Стиль для блока категории **/
#block-category{
width: 220px;
height: auto;
}
#block-category > ul{
margin-top: -5px;
}

.header-title{
width: 210px;
font: 14px sans-serif;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
color: white;
background: url(/images/grd-title.png);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0  0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0  0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0  0; 
}

#block-category > ul > li{
border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;

}
#block-category > ul > li > a{
font: 15px sans-serif;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 30px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}
#block-category > ul > li > a:hover{
background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#block-category > ul > li > a.active{
background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

#syvenir-images{
position: absolute;
margin-left: -26px;
margin-top: -3px;
}
#svetilnik-images{
position: absolute;
margin-left: -30px;
margin-top: -2px;
}
#year-images{
position: absolute;
margin-left: -30px;
}
.category-section{
margin-left: 25px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
display: none;
}
.category-section li{
margin-top: 3px;
}
.category-section a{
font: 15px sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
.category-section a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Доброе утро. Список нормально отображается. У Вас, скорей всего, проблема с css, что не даёт отобразить вложенные списки

Comment: @slo_nik Получается приложить еще и css вам?

Comment: Мне css совершенно не нужен. Вы смотрите сами, через инспектор кода. А Ваш код я скопировал, запустил и увидел, что всё прекрасно отображается, так, как Вы показали на первом изображении.

Comment: Можете убедиться сами https://itmages.ru/image/view/6549512/086ceb22
Так что проблема в css.

Comment: @slo_nik Я разрабатываю проект в phpDesigner и у меня ничего не получается изменить. Если я просто создаю обычную html страницу, то у меня нормально всё отображается http://prntscr.com/itodvg
Но а если в самом проекте + css, то возникает проблема http://prntscr.com/itoeen

Comment: Исправьте свой css, проблема плёвая, не стоит из-за подобной проблемы создавать вопрос. Правой кнопкой "мыши" на меню  -> "исследовать элемент" или "посмотреть код"(зависит от браузера) -> в открывшейся панели, справа, будут css стили. Вот внимательно посмотрите и увидите, какое правило надо убрать.

Comment: @slo_nik пытаюсь это сделать, но пока что не получается ничего

Answer (score 0):

Всё, нашёл проблему. Оказывается у меня в классе category-section стоял запрет отображения (display: none;)

Comment: Ну наконец-то!!!)))